# How to replace regex pattern in a string android

Tags: android, regex, string

I'm having the string in html format.My regular expression pattern is

> en-media[^>]*hash='4854-621-780'[^>]*

I want to replace the pattern into

> img src='mnt/sdcard/img1'

How to replace this in a html string android.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thanks:)

Comment: Can you give an example input and example result that you want.  What should the String src have in it when done?

Answer (score 0):

Like @hack_on said I'm not sure what you want to replace the pattern with, but would something like this work:

```
String dst = src.replaceAll("en-media[^>]hash='4854-621-780'[^>]", aReplacementString);
```